# Ruby, Cucumber and Watir Automation Scripting Basics

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, watir

Thank y'all all within the community and the moderators for being so cool and willing to help so quickly! Just wanted to lead in with that. So I could really use some help with this basic automation script that I am running. I am trying to select the search bar on Google.com and enter some text. I have gotten some help from friends but they were stuck as well. But it learning this I was hoping to get some help from the experts and just ask these questions that I have because Google ain't got shit!

1) How to select the search field and enter text.

Mine looks something like this I've tried xpath, different values, id's classes.

```
require 'ruby' 
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Browser::browser.new :firefox 
browser.goto 'http://google.com'
browser.text_field(:value => 'Search').set('google search')
```

2) When I inspect the element and find unique characteristics to that value (i.e. href, id, title, class, name), which are the ones that I can actually utilize to call either the button, text_field, or link?

3) I understand html and css pretty well. Can someone please explain how to properly utilize xpath?

Y'all rock, I feel like there are tons of people out there who have these same questions as I do, and can't find the damn answers anywhere, so I ask all of you automation experts, would you mind dropping a knowledge bomb and learnin us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in this script.  Here's a working version:

```
# require 'ruby'                         # don't require ruby
require 'watir-webdriver'                # corrected typo in gem name

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox    # corrected Browser::browser.new
browser.goto 'http://google.com'
browser.text_field(:title => 'Search').set('google search') # changed :value to :title
```

In terms of identifying [page elements](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Page-Elements), it's generally considered good practice to use the `id` attribute since it's unique to the page.  You can use the attributes that you've listed, but they have to exist as attributes for the given HTML element.  AFAIK, watir-webdriver supports using the majority of standard HTML tag attributes for location and can also locate elements based on their index, via regular expression, and by combining multiple locators.  For example, you could substitute any of these in the script above:

```
browser.text_field(:title => /Search/).set('google search')
browser.text_field(:class => 'gsfi').set('google search')
browser.text_field(:id => 'lst-ib').set('google search') 
browser.text_field(:name=> 'q', :class => 'gsfi').set('google search')
```

If you haven't already, I'd suggest checking out http://watirwebdriver.com/ and https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki.  And if you're curious about using xpath to find tricky elements, check out 
https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/locate-element-via-custom-attribute-css-and-xpath/.

Comment: Wow brother thank you so much for the input that was some really good information I have actually used it to as a reference for some basic scripts and it has worked like a charm.

Comment: I do have one more question for you though. There are certain things that I am trying to automate as practice such as sending a thank you email to family members. I get logged in and all the way to the gmail inbox, however cannot figure out how to reference the "compose" button. I was wondering if you could help me with that? Also my other question is are there certain things that the browser or site wont let you automate or this there always a way to reference any html element?

Comment: Best bet is submit a new question with the minimal code needed to repro the issue.  Otherwise, information gets lost in the comments.